# Why can't PHP find an element that is reachable using JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been staring at this problem for hours. For the life of me, I cannot find an explanation. PHP cannot find the userid and subgenre elements. All the others are found.

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="php/writers.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload-target" onsubmit="startUpload();" >
    <h1>Writers</h1>
    <p>
        <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control"  placeholder="Title" required autofocus="true" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="work-type" class="fixed50">Form:</label>
        <select id="work-type" name="work-type">
            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="non-fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
            <option value="screenplay">Screenplay</option>
            <option value="play">Play</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <p>For an explanation of the genres shown here, see <a target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genres">List of genres</a></p>
        <label for="genre"  class="fixed50">Genre:</label>
        <select id="genre" name="genre">
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="subgenre" class="fixed50">Sub-Genre:</label>
        <select id="subgenre" name="subgenre">`
            <option value="0">None</option>
        </select><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="nbrPages" class="fixed50">Number of pages:</label>
        <input id="nbrPages" name="nbrPages" required style="width: 48px" placeholder="Pages" /><br/>
    </p>
    <p>For a limied time, writers can upload their sysnopsis or query letterr for <span style="color: #f00; font-weight:bold">FREE</span>. We reserve the right to change this policy without notice.</p>
    <div id="tips">The objective of a sysnopsis or query letter is to entice enablers into requesting your manuscript. 
                    It must be brief and to the point, now more than twp pages and, of course very well written.
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p id="file-warning">Your synopsis or query letter must be a PDF file.
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freepdfconvert.com/" target="_blank">Free file conversion to PDF</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file2upload">PDF to Upload</label>
        <input id="file2upload" name="file2upload" type="file" required value="File to upload" />
    </div>
    <div id="recaptcha-elements"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="writers-submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <input id="userid" name="userid" type="hidden" />
    <iframe id="upload-target" name="upload-target" src="#" ></iframe>                 
</form>
```

The following JS function writes the correct values to the console.

**JS**

```
function startUpload() {
    $("#userid").val(window.localStorage.getItem('user-id'));
    console.log("jquery val=" + $("#subgenre").val());
    console.log("getElementById value=" + document.getElementById('subgenre').value);
    showMessage(1, "Uploading...");
    return true;
}
```

**console.log**

> userid=51  VM39985:122
>
> jquery val=0  VM39985:123
>
> getElementById value=0
>
> /php/writers.php:1 POST  500 (Internal Server
>    Error)

**PHP**

```
$uploadDirectory = '/home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/uploads/'; //specify upload directory ends with / (slash)
require_once "dbconnect.php";
$result = 0;
$File_Name          = basename($_FILES['file2upload']['name']);
$File_Ext           = substr($File_Name, strrpos($File_Name, '.')); //get file extention
$Random_Number      = rand(0, 9999999999); //Random number to be added to name.
$NewFileName        = $Random_Number.$File_Ext; //new file name

var_dump($_REQUEST); 
$target_path = $uploadDirectory . $NewFileName;

if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file2upload']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $uploadDirectory . $NewFileName);
    finfo_close($finfo); 
    if ($mime_type != 'application/pdf') {
        unlink($UploadDirectory . $NewFileName);
        $data = array('File MUST be a PDF!');
        $result = 0;
    } else $result = 1;
}
if (!isset($_REQUEST["title"]) || empty(trim($_REQUEST["title"])))
    throw new Exception('You must enter a title.');       
else {
    $title = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["title"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $title = htmlspecialchars_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES);
}
if (!isset($_REQUEST["userid"]) || empty(trim($_REQUEST["userid"])))
    throw new Exception('Userid is missing.');       
else {
    $userrid = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["userid"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $userid = htmlspecialchars_decode($userid, ENT_QUOTES);
}
if (!isset($_REQUEST["work-type"]) || empty(trim($_REQUEST["work-type"])))
    throw new Exception('You must enter a work type.');       
else {
    $worktype = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["work-type"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $worktype = htmlspecialchars_decode($worktype, ENT_QUOTES);
}
if (!isset($_REQUEST["genre"]) || empty(trim($_REQUEST["genre"])))
    throw new Exception('You must enter a title.');       
else {
    $genre = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["genre"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $genre = htmlspecialchars_decode($genre, ENT_QUOTES);
}
if (!isset($_REQUEST["subgenre"]) || empty(trim($_REQUEST["subgenre"])))
    throw new Exception('You must enter a sub-genre.');       
else {
    $subgenre = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["subgenre"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $subgenre = htmlspecialchars_decode($subgenre, ENT_QUOTES);
}
if (!isset($_REQUEST["nbrPages"]) || empty(trim($_REQUEST["nbrPages"])))
    throw new Exception('You must enter the number of pages your work contains.');       
else {
    $nbrPages = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["nbrPages"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $nbrPages = htmlspecialchars_decode($nbrPages, ENT_QUOTES);
}

$dbh = connect2DB();
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(
    "INSERT Writers(fkAccounts, Title, WorkType, Genre, SubGenre, Filename) 
    VALUES(:fk, :title, :worktype, :genre, :subgenre, :filename)"
);

$stmt->bindParam(':fk', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
$stmt->bindParam(':worktype', $worktype, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
$stmt->bindParam(':genre', $genre, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$stmt->bindParam(':subgenre', $subgenre, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$stmt->bindParam(':filename', $NewFileName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);

$stmt->execute();


echo "<script type='text/javascript'>stopUpload(" . $result . ");</script>";
sleep(1);
exit();

$data = array();
require_once 'cookies.php';

if (isset($_REQUEST['files'])) {  
    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        if ($file["size"] > $filesize_limit) {
//            $data = array('Maximum file size (' . $filesize_limit . ') exeeded.');
//            $error = true;
        } else {
            $File_Name          = basename($file['name']);
            $File_Ext           = substr($File_Name, strrpos($File_Name, '.')); //get file extention
            $Random_Number      = rand(0, 9999999999); //Random number to be added to name.
            $NewFileName        = $Random_Number.$File_Ext; //new file name

            if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory . $NewFileName)) {
                $files[] = $UploadDirectory . $file['name']; //$NewFileName; // 
                $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $UploadDirectory . $NewFileName);
                //$data = array('Mime-Type (' . $mime_type . ')');
                finfo_close($finfo); 
                if ($mime_type != 'application/pdf') {
                    unlink($UploadDirectory . $NewFileName);
                    $data = array('File MUST be a PDF!');
                    $error = true;
                };
            } else {
                $error = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($error) {
        $data = array('error' => $data);
    } else {
        $data = array('files' => $files);
    }
} else {
    $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_REQUEST);
};

echo json_encode($data);
```

**PHP error_log**

> [17-May-2016 00:59:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: userid in
>   /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/writers.php on line 34
>
> [17-May-2016 00:59:49 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
>
> [17-May-2016 00:59:49 UTC] PHP   1. {main}()
>   /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/writers.php:0
>
> [17-May-2016 00:59:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Exception' with message 'You must enter a sub-genre.' in
>   /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/writers.php:49
>
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/writers.php on line 49

Comment: if value may change after load then php can't pick that value. Coz it is server side scripting language.

Comment: I'm ***really*** confused, you clearly have an undefined variable, the error code plainly tells you which one it is, on what line it's on, an why it's an error ?

Comment: Try typing it correctly -> `$userid = htmlspecialchars_decode($userrid, ENT_QUOTES);`

Comment: And the next time, you won't use confusing variable names

Comment: I m equally confused. I checked all the usual suspects; the names are correctly defined on the form. I even wrote their values in JS to the console to prove to myself they were reachable. Perplexing isn't it.

Comment: @adeno - great eyes. One down. How about the subgenre?

Comment: @andeno. Please explain why you think the variable names are confusing

Comment: It throws because the condition is falsy, generally `empty(trim("0"))` is truthy.

Comment: The variables names are confusing because you use `$userrid` and `$userid`, and you sure seemed to be confused by the similarity ?

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks so  much. Please prepare an answer so I can reward your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're passing a non-existing variable to a function, on these two lines

```
$userrid = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["userid"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$userid = htmlspecialchars_decode($userid, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Where `$userid` isn't defined when you do the call to `htmlspecialchars_decode`, it's a typo where you probably intended to type

```
$userrid = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["userid"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$userid = htmlspecialchars_decode($userrid, ENT_QUOTES);
```

The second error is that PHP is throwing on this line

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST["subgenre"]) || empty(trim($_REQUEST["subgenre"])))
    throw new Exception('You must enter a sub-genre.');
```

That's because the condition is thruthy.
The select element with the name `subgenre` has a value of `0`, and in PHP `empty(trim("0"));` is thruthy, hence the if condition enters, and the exception is thrown.